# Problem with display manager in several kernels

Tags: kernel, lightdm

I'm having a problem starting the GUI on several kernels - now for a while and it is getting more severe now:

The general problem is, that the boot of the system stops at the point when starting lightdm (same problem exists for gdm). This isn't true for all kernels, but the last one that worked was

> uname -a
> Linux bs-L 5.4.0-96-generic #109-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 12 16:49:16 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

To overcome this problem I did now a release-upgrade - which was a mistake obviously. On the kernel 5.15.0.56 it soesn't work, similar to 5.4.0-131, 5.4.0-132 or 5.4.0-135.
Since the new release has problems with the old kernel versions, now some things don't work anymore. So the problem becomes more urgent.

So, in the syslog I find the following things on lightdm:

```
Dec  5 08:43:49 bs-L lightdm[4571]: Seat type 'xlocal' is deprecated, use 'type=local' instead
Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: gpu-manager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: gpu-manager.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.  Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec  5 08:43:50 bs-L systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
```

Has anyone an idea on howto overcome this problem?

Comment: You should provide release details; you mention both 5.4 & 5.15 & a *release-upgrade*, but not if you're talking about the GA or HWE kernel stack, thus we cannot know which release you upgraded from & to (two options exist depending on which kernel stack you were using, but you didn't specify).  Please provide release details or do you expect us to guess?  (*Ubuntu LTS releases offer kernel stack choices; with the default chosen by the installation media, though for some ISOs you can choose at login, but you've not specified if desktop/server or what release/media was used*)

Comment: It was from 20.04 to 22.04 both the LTS version. It is all on Dell latitude 5401 laptop.

`lspci
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)

Comment: A single google search indicates that GeForce MX150 / GT1030 are 2017:ish hardware, I recollect that some GPU models has been dropped from the recent nVidia drivers - might it be your actual problem? I suggest you research which driver ACTUALLY works for your GPU.

Comment: @Hannu According to Nvidia the MX150 is not legacy hardware therefore still supported by the newest driver version.

Comment: So; now we *know* that :-)